# PICKLE Pic Programmer on RPi 4 Model B

Tags: hex, pic, raspberry-pi4

Has anybody used this application PICKLE https://wiki.kewl.org/dokuwiki/projects:pickle with a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B?

PICKLE is an application developed in "C", which allows the RPi to use its GPIO pins to program a .hex file in a number of PIC microcontrollers

I can install and run the code, but the GPIOs do not respond correctly (PICKLE has a 'ptest' command that allows you to toggle the GPIO specified in a .pickle configuration file)

I know that the GPIO pins are working because I can toggle them with the standard 'echo 1/0' approach. I suspect the problem I have is with a driver called gpio_bb -- has anybody used this driver?

Some additional info

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a**

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.32-v7l+ #1538 SMP Thu Mar 31 19:39:41 BST 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release: 11
Codename: bullseye
```

Output from running the ptest command:

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ptest PGC 5**

```
TEST VPP|PGD|PGC|PGM OUTPUT

PGC LOW  (ICSP 5) (D-SUB-9 RTS 7) [3 seconds]
PGC HIGH (ICSP 5) (D-SUB-9 RTS 7) [5 seconds]
PGC LOW  (ICSP 5) (D-SUB-9 RTS 7) [3 seconds]

TEST DONE
```

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ptest PGD 5**

```
TEST VPP|PGD|PGC|PGM OUTPUT

PGD LOW  (ICSP 4) (D-SUB-9 DTR 3) [3 seconds]
PGD HIGH (ICSP 4) (D-SUB-9 DTR 3) [5 seconds]
PGD LOW  (ICSP 4) (D-SUB-9 DTR 3) [3 seconds]

TEST DONE
```

.pickle file is shown below

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat .pickle**

```
DEVICE=RPI
SLEEP=1
BITRULES=0x1000
PGC=5
PGD=6
VPP=13
PGM=-1  #19
DEBUG=1
CONFIG=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the documentation says to use device=RPI in the .pickle configuration file (PICKLE should autodetect the RPi model), in reality, it needs device=RPI4

The ptest utility now correctly drives the GPIO pins